# Javascript Precedence of Parenthesis

Tags: javascript

I'm playing with Rhino and noticed this strange behavior in what appears to be operator precedence:

```
js> {}+{}
NaN
js> ''+{}+{}
[object Object][object Object]
js> ''+({}+{})
[object Object][object Object]
```

I would expect the expression `''+({}+{})` to evaluate to `"NaN"`, since `{}+{}` should be evaluated first, yet this does not happen. I tested this out in V8 and Firefox and got the same result.

Why does it appear that Javascript does not follow the standard precedence given to parenthesis in this case (`4*(1+2)` is still the expected `12`)?

Comment: console.log( {}+{} ); too gives [object Object][object Object]

Comment: @Sudhir yes, because being inside parentheses means it's an expression and not a statement.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for clarification, didn't think abt that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A plain `{}` is treated as a block statement so your code is actually:

```
{
  //empty block
}


+{}; //Convert object to number
```

I should explain what plain means:

It means `{}` in a statement context. `({})` is an object because parentheses cannot contain statements, they can only contain expressions.

Comment: @lanzz I should rephrase that. By **plain** I mean `{}` without anything else as a statement. It is treated as a block. `{hello: "world", hi: "again"}` is a syntax error. `{hello: "world"}` is a block, label and a string.

Comment: That's the right answer. The first `{}` is interpreted as block, the second one as object literal. @Travis: The parenthesis work as expected, your assunption, the result of `{}+{}` being `NaN`, was incorrect.

Comment: +1 Yes. Trying `({} + {})` (which yields "[object Object][object Object]") demonstrates this.

Comment: @lanzz: No, the problem is with the first statement. Travis thinks the addition of two object literals yields `NaN` which is not true. `({} + {})` yields `[object Object][object Object]`. `{} + {}` yields `NaN` because the first one is not interpreted as object literal. The whole assumption this experiment is based on is faulty.

Comment: True, I'm apparently still asleep.

Comment: Now I get it - I had a misinterpretation of the first statement's output. More simply: `+{}` is `NaN`, which makes sense.

Comment: A fine example of JavaScript syntax **abuse**. I know why I consider this language to be a hack.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse it's the logical consequence of using `{}` both for blocks and object literals in a dynamically typed language.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse nobody would actually write that in real code anyway, it's only common when playing with a console. With real code you would at least try to assign to variable or pass it to a function or whatever else that would force an expression context.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple:

```
{}
```

is a statement, and:

```
({})
```

is an expression.

Only the latter (or anything else that coerces the interpreter into treating the braces as an empty object) will result in `[object Object]`.